# Static / Fixed Column or slide with bxSlider?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using  bxSlider & want a static or fixed column on the left that does not slide.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is difficult to add it to the plugin. You probably can add the bxslider content in a relative positioned container. Place the static content as absolutely positioned over the slider.

Added an example fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sreecheck/27pmxv22/2/

```css
.outer{
    position:relative;
}
div.noslide{
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:30%;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

<ul class="bxslider">
    <li class="slide"><div>Slide 1</div></li>
    <li  class="slide"><div>Slide 2</div></li>
    <li  class="slide"><div>Slide 3</div></li>
</ul>
    <div  class="noslide">Static</div>
</div>
```

I guess you would have already tried this out. Not be the cleanest, but hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines as one solution.  I was wondering if you could use some of the bxSlider JS callback functions to change the element index #'s so that one slide always has the same index.